# Ebean record fails to pick up on a relationship

Tags: java, sql, orm, playframework, ebean

I am having trouble with Ebean/Play not properly picking up licks between tables.

I have 3 tables, **Users**, **Groups** and **UsersGroups** (bridge).

I have a record in each table and when I pick up a **Users** record, the object has access to all associated **UsersGroups** records. However when I try to do the same for **Groups** the linked **UsersGroups** object is empty. I have little experience with ORMs and have no idea how I can debug this issue.

Users class:

```
@Entity
public class Users extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long intUserId;

    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 50, unique = true)
    @Constraints.Required
    public String strUsername;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Sessions> session;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<UsersGroups> memberOfGroups;


    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 50)
    public String strFirstName;

    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 50)
    public String strLastName;

    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 50, unique = true)
    @Constraints.Required
    public String strEmail;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date tsRegistrationDate = new Date();

    public String strPasswordHash;

    public static Finder<Long, Users> find = new Finder(Long.class, Users.class);
}
```

Groups class:

```
@Entity
public class Groups extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long intGroupId;

    @Transient
    public Long intToken() {
        return this.intGroupId + 100000;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<UsersGroups> usersGroups;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date tsCreated = new Date();

    @Constraints.Required
    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 2)
    public Long intType;

    @Constraints.Required
    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 2)
    public Long intStatus = (long) 1;

    @Constraints.Required
    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 50)
    public String strName;

    @Constraints.Required
    public boolean blPublic;

    public static Finder<Long, Groups> find = new Finder(Long.class, Groups.class);
}
```

Bridge Class:

```
@Entity
public class UsersGroups extends Model {

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "int_user_id")
    public Users member;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "int_group_id")
    public Groups group;

    public int type;


    public static Finder<Long, UsersGroups> find = new Finder(Long.class, UsersGroups.class);



}
```

Now my issue:

```
System.out.println("GROUP: "+ group.intGroupId);
System.out.println("UGROUP: "+ Ebean.group(UsersGroups.class ).where().eq("int_group_id", group.intGroupId).findRowCount());
System.out.println(group.usersGroups.size());
```

Prints:

```
GROUP: 12
UGROUP: 1
0
```

From this I gather that 1. my groups object is found, 2. the associated record in the bridge table is found, 3. Ebean fails to pick up the link.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should include the generated SQL statements in your question?